# undefined reference in cs50 week 1 course

Tags: c, cs50

I am enrolled in CS50. I am working on the week 1 project. #include  at the top of the program is supposed to have certain programs already defined, such as get_string, get_int, etc... Before I get into the project I ran a simple test to make sure everything was working.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
    {
        printf("What is your name?\n");
        string x = get_string("x");
        printf("Hello, %x!");
    }
```

My code is above and below is the error I keep receiving.

```
undefined reference to `get_string'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Aren't those errors already referenced when I put in #include ?

Comment: When I try to compile this program in the sandbox (and the ide) it complains about the invalid syntax in the `printf` command. More correct syntax would be: `printf("Hello, %s!",x);`

Answer (score 3):

That's a linker error, not a compiler error. The problem is that you included `cs50.h`, which has the declaration of `get_string`, but you didn't include the library that has its definition. To fix it, pass `-lcs50` on the command line.

Comment: Below is what I typed in the command line:    $ -lcs50
-lcs50: command not found
$ lcs50
lcs50: command not found

Comment: @user3553965 I meant to add that as an argument to clang, not to run it on its own.

Comment: Sorry. This is my first week of computer science class. So now I ran $ clang -lcs50 and I got the error below
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @user3553965 To the clang command you're running to compile your code, not in a new clang command by itself.

Comment: https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/ this should give you step-by-step instructions as well as a troubleshooting guide.